Keep scroll bar Y position after re-render in react
I tried all other similar questions here but there were about 3 years ago questions and answers which's not working right now.
So I have a child component which contains table and in the parent component by changing its wrapping div key value it redirects the child component and after render the component scroll bar keeps going to the top.
<div className="flex justify-center p-5" key={keyValue}>
  <MatchedRows
    data={data}
    data2={data2}
    onItemChange2={onItemChange2}
    onItemChange={onItemChange}
  />
</div>


I fixed this issue through implementing useLayoutEffect and sessionStorage.
sessionStorage.setItem(`tableScrollPosition`, mtableRef.current.scrollTop);
const savedScrollPosition = sessionStorage.getItem(`tableScrollPosition`);
if (savedScrollPosition && mtableRef.current) {
    mtableRef.current.scrollTop = parseInt(savedScrollPosition, 10);
}

